# What does the "at any level" refer to or imply? Any level of what? Level of road? Level of driving?

Tags: word-meaning

So today we want to talk about the subject of defensive driving. And the way I define defensive driving is, the ability to develop the proper driving habits, so that we can compensate for pretty much anything that goes on out on the roadways and that we can avoid a crash **at any level**.

And could you also please paraphrase the whole text in simple English?

Answer (score 1):

Today we are going to discuss driving defensively (being mindful/careful of other cars on the road and potential road hazards so you can avoid accidents). My definition of defensive driving is having good driving habits, so that you can avoid anything potentially dangerous on the road and avoid getting into a collision with another car **in any situation or road/weather condition**.

Don't feel bad if you don't understand what they mean by "at any level." It is a little weird in this context for me too.